# What Legends material did The Force Awakens explicitly contradict?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends

*Star Wars Legends* (formally the *Star Wars Expanded Universe*) already had lots of events set after *Star Wars VI: Return of the Jedi*.

Did *Star Wars VII: The Force Awakens* explicitly contradict any of those events? If yes (most likely), what are they?

---

NOTE: some of the suggested events were NOT explicitly contradicted by canon.

- Imperial Remnant could still have happened.
- Mara Jade could still have happened (that might change by Episode VIII of course).
- Even Han and Leia having twins is NOT directly contradicted by new canon — nowhere does it say Ben didn't have a twin (we know Rey isn't that twin as she is 10 years younger)

Comment: well, pretty much everything ever published after RotJ for starters...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I think the question is a bit different than that. Even though non canon disney can still use the EU material. But some things like the twins birth CAN no longer exist at all (ok currently not 100% that it doesn't exist with the infos we have so far but it is still a good example)

Comment: The twins, or Mara, or anything including a new Jedi order, or anything not including the First Order, or...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - Mara doesn't contradict any existing Disney canon so far. Neither do twins since we don't know Ben was an only child for sure. Ditto Imperial Remnant -  they could have existed alongside FO. Frankly, this is an amazing question and is mostly getting poor reaction based on who asked it, if you actually dig into deep canon.

Comment: +1 there's a big, big difference between "doesn't follow" (>95%) and "directly contradicts" (<5%)

Comment: Huge sections are still compatible -Thrawn trilogy with very little changes, 95% of pre-Episode VI content. YV War given its proximity in time to TFA probably is contradicted, as is everything after

Comment: @SSumner - Re: YV: not really contradicted eitrher. Just move Vector Prime from 25ABY to after the Episode VII, and get Han out of the picture, and YW was is still feasible.

Comment: @DVK okay true I was thinking of in the ABY timeline as stated but if you move stuff around sure...although that makes the main characters reaaaaaally old

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some things that are 100% contradicted:

- The capital of the New Republic is NOT on Coruscant as it is in EU.

  - This challenges any events related to Coruscant, such as Thrawn's offensive on it - but quite possibly, simply moves them to a new capital.
- Based on the way Snoke and Ren talk about him, the Emperor Palpatine never got himself resurrected into a clone
- Any adventures that Han and Leia had together as a couple (which doesn't invalidate larger historical events around those adventures)
- Any NJO adventures between when Ben turned (no exact info but presumably at 15) till 30+ ABY, given that Luke's NJO was Kylorenned out.
- Chewie did not die in Yuuzhan Vong invasion as he did in Vector Prime, since that book happened in 25ABY, definitely before TFA (which is 30+ years after Endor). That death could have happened AFTER TFA however, if they move YV up the timeline.

---

Things that are NOT explicitly contradicted (though implicitly clearly are unlikely to have happened, at least in un-modified form or on precise EU schedule):

- Thrawn invasion. We don't have any direct proof it never happened.

  - Amazingly, even the specific subplot of Luke fighting his own clone armed with Bespin lightsaber isn't contradicted - that may very well have been how the LS was retrieved to end up with Maz Kanata.
- Some of earlier New Jedi Order events (they could have happened before Kylo Ren destroyed Luke's academy)
- For that matter, Yoozhan Vong invasion, is not directly contradicted either as a past event (it doesn't get mentioned, granted, and likely would have been), or as a future event.
- Pretty much all of Old Republic and before material.

Comment: Ben Solo exists in the Legends?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - well, he's called Jacen Solo. And seems a lot less like a whiney teenager, usually. But as far as high level story arc goes, I say he's a pretty close parallel, what with Jacen's outcome.

Comment: What I really want to dig out is any things that rely exclusively on R2D2 to fix in EU.

Comment: Also, Chewbacca isn't dead anymore.

Comment: Ben/Kylo is still han & Leia's son, right? So some adventures could still have them as a couple, right?

Comment: @SSumner - they split up some undefined time back....

Comment: @DvK right but that doesn't rule out *any* adventure together

Comment: More importantly, is it still possible for us to have Tonin, King of the Droids, and his army of mouse droids?

Comment: Just to point out the Capital of the New Republic moved during the events of NJO off of Coruscant. So there's actually an EU precedent for that.

Comment: "Based on the way Snoke and Ren talk about him, the Emperor Palpatine never got himself resurrected into a clone" I think this part isn't right anymore... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No Mara Jade, Han and Leia have only one child instead of 3 and didn't have a "strained/separated" relationship. 
If you want to get technical, it's all contradicted since Grand Admiral Thrawn began his campaign roughly 5 years after ROTJ.
He has since been retconned into canon, but in events that happened earlier and only in novels.